# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline Command line task cannot find specified Working Directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When running a Command Line task during a Release deployment (Windows Server) I'm trying to set the working directory to a folder outside of the Agent's working folders, and it's failing with the error:

`Container path not found: 'D:\myfolder\scripts_to_run'`

Yaml:

```
steps:
- script: 'py -3 Hello.py'
  workingDirectory: 'D:\myfolder\scripts_to_run'
  displayName: 'Check python'
```

This is working correctly on two other Windows machines.

You may ask why I'm calling this Python Script in a command prompt. It's because I was getting another error when trying to use the Python task directly:

`##[error]ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'D:\myfolder\scripts_to_run\hello.py'`

Yaml:

```
steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'Run Database SQL Script updater '
  inputs:
    scriptPath: 'D:\myfolder\scripts_to_run\hello.py'
    arguments: '-3'
    workingDirectory: 'D:\myfolder\scripts_to_run'
    failOnStderr: true
```

I should precise that folders and files certainly do exist. They're not deployed with the release; they're always present. They're run at the end of a release deployment to do a few utility tasks.

I'm wondering if it's a file/folder permissions issue.

Edit: I previously mentioned that the agent was already correctly deploying an IIS web site in the same directory tree, but that was false. It was a previous stage running a **Deployment Group Job** not and **Agent Job**.

Comment: Share your entire pipeline. The error message is telling you the problem, so it's either a problem with the pipeline itself (i.e. you're *not* actually running the step on the machine you think you're running it on), or the files really *aren't* present on the machine where you think they are.

Comment: @DanielMann you hit the nail on the head. It was the wrong type of agent.

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction; I suspected that was the case but since you didn't provide your full YAML I couldn't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solved. I had created an agent job instead of a deployment group job!
Agent jobs do not run in the same context as deployment group jobs.

This explains the differences:
[What are the differences between an Agent Job and a Deployment Group Job in Azure DevOps?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58637162/9160880)